# Make a copy of a set and exclude one item

Tags: python, set

Im trying to make a set based in another set, and exclude only one item... 
(do a for loop inside another for loop with an object that is inside a set, but not iterate with itself on the second loop)

Code:

```
for animal in self.animals:
    self.exclude_animal = set((animal,))
    self.new_animals = set(self.animals)
    self.new_animals.discard(self.exclude_animal) # parameters for a set needs to be a set?

    for other_animal in (self.new_animals):
        if animal.pos[0] == other_animal.pos[0]:
            if animal.pos[1] == other_animal.pos[1]:
                self.animals_to_die.add(animal)
                print other_animal
                print animal
                self.animals_to_die.add(other_animal)
```

Point is, my print statement returns the object `id(x)`, so I know that they are the same object, but they should not be, I discard it on that set `new_animals` set.

Any insight in why this doesn't exclude the item?

Comment: Perhaps `discard` returns a new set rather than modifying the old one? Sets might be immutable but I can't remember.

Comment: @WaleedKhan: `set.discard()` operates in-place. `set()` is mutable, `frozenset()` is not and doesn't have a `.discard()` method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`set.discard()` removes *one* item from the set, but you pass in a whole set object.

You need to remove the element **itself**, not another set with the element inside:

```
self.new_animals.discard(animal)
```

Demo:

```
>>> someset = {1, 2, 3}
>>> someset.discard({1})
>>> someset.discard(2)
>>> someset
set([1, 3])
```

Note how `2` was removed, but `1` remained in the set.

It would be easier to just loop over the set difference here:

```
for animal in self.animals:    
    for other_animal in set(self.animals).difference([animal]):
        if animal.pos == other_animal.pos:
            self.animals_to_die.add(animal)
            print other_animal
            print animal
            self.animals_to_die.add(other_animal)
```

(where I assume that `.pos` is a tuple of two values, you can just test for direct equality here).

You don't need to store `new_animals` on `self` all the time; using local names suffices and is not even needed here.

Comment: I think the OP might have been trying to do: `self.new_animals = self.animals.difference([animal])`

Comment: Indeed i tried that too, along with a dozen of ways, using lists instead of sets (Oh god why i did that.)...
It still isnt working they way it should, but i have more stuff to fix and print in order to actually see if that was the only problem i have... Thanks for the answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As you mark both animals to die, you don't need to compare A to B and also B to A (which your current code does). You can ensure you get only unique pairs of animals by using `itertools.combinations()`:

```
for animal, other_animal in itertools.combinations(self.animals, 2):
    if animal.pos==other_animal.pos:
        self.animals_to_die.update([animal, other_animal])
```

Just for fun, I'll point out you can even do it as a single expression (though I think it reads better as an explicit loop):

```
self.animals_to_die.update(sum(((animal,other_animal)
    for animal,other_animal in itertools.combinations(self.animals, 2)
    if animal.pos == other_animal.pos), ()))
```

For clarity, `itertools.combinations()` gives you all the unique combinations of its input. The second argument controls how many elements are selected each time:

```
>>> list(itertools.combinations(["A", "B", "C", "D"], 2))
[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), ('C', 'D')]
>>> list(itertools.combinations(["A", "B", "C", "D"], 3))
[('A', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'B', 'D'), ('A', 'C', 'D'), ('B', 'C', 'D')]
```

That works well in this case as the code given appears to be symmetric (two animals on the same location mutually annihilate each other). If it had been asymmetric (one kills the other) then you would have to remember to test both ways round on each iteration.

Comment: Nice idea: `self.animals_to_die.update([animal, other_animal])` would work nicely as well...

Comment: I was trying to make too many assumptions about the type of `animals_to_die`, but let's go with it.

Comment: Animals_to_die is a list of objects animal. Question, that first code with the For and itertools thing... Is going to test each item on the list against all the others?

Comment: @Matg0d, `itertools.combinations()` will pair the first animal with all but itself, then the second with all but the first and itself, and so on. So yes it pairs every animal with every other, but each pair only appears once unlike your code where you pair A,B and then later B,A.